# Tableau blended data show null values as zero

Tags: null, tableau-api

Blended data contains null values which I would like to show as zeros.

Is there a neat way to do this without introducing additional measures?

How do I attach a file to this query as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a measure that contains `Null` values you usually get a notification on the bottom right corner of the Tableau window on how many `null` values there are. If you click on it you can define what should happen with these (eg. "Show data at default position" - which is 0)
[image]